# How to change my git point to gitlab or AWS CodeCommit?

Tags: git, amazon-ec2, gitlab, aws-codecommit

Initially I used git to access my gitlab repository to all my push and pull operation. Today I tried to deploy my branch directly on AWS EBS with CLI. By mistake I create codeCommit from the same directory which used for gitlab.So now when I tired to push my code it expecting to connect to codeCommit but I want it to push to gitlab. Anyone have idea about the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your git remote. You can also add multiple remotes, by default it uses the one named "origin".

See manual: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote

```
# list current remote:
$ git remote -v

# update git remote url:
$ git remote set-url origin git@....

# add new remote named "gitlab":
$ git remote add gitlab git@gitlab.com:....
```

Comment: Thank you so mush i was blocked with this..once again thanks. bro it's working now..:)